# How to pass a query string variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass a class variable from 1 page to another page on link button click. The link button click event is written in the javascript query as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectTo() {
            window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx';
            return false;
        }
```

Now how can i pass a class variable through the query string? I want something like `'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?id='+Class1.ID;`

Please help me.

Comment: What you want is valid. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. But It was n't working.

Comment: Make sure `Class1.ID` is accessible and has a value within the scope of your `RedirectTo` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the value into the function, then access add it into the query string

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectTo(id) {
            window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?id=' + id;
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in code behind

```
    public string ss
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["ss"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ss"] = value;
        }
    }
```

in some mothod set ss value  like

```
ss = Class1.ID
```

in javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectTo() {
        window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.id=' + '<%= ss %>';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Might as well just embed the `<%= ss %>` within the string and skip the concatenation. And the URL is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectTo() {
        window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?Id=' +Id;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

In C# Code

```
   if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null) {
        try
        {
            id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        }
        catch
        {
            // deal with it
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `public static` property within a class, then you can access it like so;

```
window.location.href = '<%=string.format("ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?id={0}", MyClass.id)%> ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set class value into hidden field and send that value

**Js code:**

```
var getValue= $("#hiddenField1").val();
window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?id=' + getValue;
```

**Code behind:** On ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx.cs

```
if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
string fetch_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the class in your page, you can do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectTo() {
            window.location.href = 'ApplyJobsByCandidate.aspx?id=<% =Class1.ID %>';
            return false;
        }
```